# What is the maximum file size we can copy to a custom partition using "wic cp" command for an yocto image?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-wic

I am trying to copy a folder to a custom partition using `wic cp` command. The file size is 5.1gb,
after copying it into partition, when I boot the image and check, it shows only 1GB. So, my question is: Is there any limit to the file size we can copy using `wic cp` command?

In local.conf I have:

```
IMAGE_FSTYPE = "wic"
WKS_FILE ?="systemd-bootdiskcustom.wks"
```

command in wks file where I have created the partition (this is the 5th partition in my image):

```
part custom_part --ondisk sda --fstype=ext4 --label custom_part --align 1024 --use-uuid --size 10000M
```

Command I use once the image is created to copy the 5.1gb file which is stored in my "meta-mylayer" is:

```
$ cd poky
$ source oe-build-env
build$ cd tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64
qemux86-64$ wic cp ../../../../../meta-mylayer/recipes-example/customfile/files/system.img core-image-custom-qemux86-64.wic:5
```

Comment: what file system you use? is it fat32? if so there is 4gb limit with fat32 file systems.

Comment: @AshokKumarThangaraj file system used is ext4, so that should not be an issue right?

Comment: Shouldn’t be a prob then. Try scp instead of cp, as scp uses ssh.

Comment: @AshokKumarThangaraj  I want to copy the file to custom partition before i flash the final image to pendrive.  We  cannot copy the files using scp. Is there any other method?

Comment: Try compressing the file into multiple zips and transfer it to the custom partition and then extract it and copy into flash drive.

Comment: @AshokKumarThangaraj i am able to compress and add it to that partition, how do i extract those files before flashing?

Comment: you can extract it using unzip filename.zip...

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to FAT32 limitation.

Files larger than 4GB cannot be stored on a FAT32 volume.

Formatting the flash drive as exFAT or NTFS will resolve this issue.

If it is not FAT32, Then try compressing the file into multiple parts and transfer in to your custom partition and extract it and copy in to your flash drive.